# Beef Bone Broth: How much should I end up with per starting bones?

Tags: broth, bones, concentration

I'm trying a beef bone broth recipe that is short on details... it basically says to cover the bones with water and simmer for 48 hours in a slow cooker.

Based on Google, other recipes don't say to cook for anywhere near that amount of time, but I decided to try it anyway.

I started with 2½ pounds of bones and about 3 quarts of water in a slow cooker.  During the 48 hours the liquid reduced enough that it was no longer covering the bones, so I added more boiling water and continued cooking.  I had to do this a total of 2 times and the final result was about 1¼ quarts of broth (after skimming the upper layer of fat).

My question is: given the initial 2½ pounds of bones, how much broth should I end up with? Is 1¼ quarts of broth going to be super-concentrated and in need of dilution, and if so, how much water should I add?

Comment: If your other recipes aren't slow-cooker specific, their timings are irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose. Just taste it. Too strong, more water, too weak, boil down. It is better to leave the lid on while boiling. That will make the broth cloudy, but more tasty.You can always filter it and clear it up with egg white.

For easy storage: boil it down, really down,and freeze. i dont think more than a litre of a kilo of bones will be very strong

Comment: BTW, I think fourty eight hours is a BIT too much. It wont hurt, but it is not necessary. A night, 12 hours is really enough.